# Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle' not found

Tags: mongodb, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm trying to install mongodb since 3 days but each time, I had a different error message until I fix some of them and I could install mongodb for my Symfony 2.1.4 installation. So now I have this error message:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle' not found"
```

I couldn't find any solution to solve it.
For information in my `composer.json` I added these lines:

```
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "*",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "v2.0.1"
```

and it creates 3 folders in the Doctrine namespace:

- doctrine/mongodb
- doctrine/mongodb-odm
- doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle

Why is this occurring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Symfony 2.1, you'll need to use version 3.0 of the [Doctrine ODM MongoDB Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html).

```
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@dev"
```

The reason the bundle you installed could not be found was because it was under a different namespace, being  `Symfony\Bundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle` for Symfony 2.0